# Primefaces and Spring Security: Ajax listener not triggered

Tags: ajax, spring, security, primefaces, actionlistener

I'm working with Primefaces 5.2 and Spring-security 4.0.1 and use NetBeans IDE (So GlassFish 4.1) and I try to make a dashboard and dynamically add wiget.

In order to deploy it on a server, I've added some security thanks to Spring Security. For the moment, it's someting very basic, using an authentication and a default filter.

So, when I launch it (the project), I'm correctly redirected to the default login page (I've configured Spring to use the 8181 port, which is for GlassFish https default port), and I log in normally.

But, from now on, when I drag a Widget from the Library Zone and drop it on the Dashboard (which actually is a datagrid inside an outputPanel inside the fieldset) zone, nothing happens. There's the same animation as usual (it disappeared and didn't go back to the library zone), but there's no widget on the dashboard, even if I refresh the page.

If I comment the filter and filter-mapping sections on web.xml, of course, there's no redirection to the login page and https protocol, but widget drop works normally.

It might also be a problem between Ajax and Spring (The function inside p:ajax is not called). Does someone have an idea to fix that?

Here's different code sections (It might be enough, if something is missing, just tell me about it)

#### web.xml File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>#{themeSwitcherBean.theme}</param-value> 
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>dashboard.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security (Disable drop????) -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### applicationContext-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- - Sample namespace-based configuration - -->

    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated" requires-channel="https"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/css" access="permitAll"/>
        <!-- Page level Spring Security : Enable Primefaces -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>

        <!-- Default Configuration: Https port for Glassfish is 8181 and not 8443 like Tomcat (http:8080, administration:4848-->
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="8080" https="8181"/>
        </port-mappings>

        <form-login />
        <logout />
        <remember-me />
        <!-- Uncomment to enable X509 client authentication support <x509 /> -->
        <!-- Uncomment to limit the number of sessions a user can have -->
        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="100"
                                             error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="md5" />
            <user-service>
                <!-- Some users -->
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

#### Droppable tag inside my xhtml page

```
<p:droppable id ="d1" for="selectedWidgets" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource=":#{p:component('groupWidgets')}">  
            <p:ajax listener="#{widgetsTableBean.onDrop}" update="dropArea"/>  
</p:droppable>
```

(selectedWidgets is the fieldset of the dashboard and dropArea the outputPanel)

#### Function call by p:ajax

```
 public void onDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Widget widget = ((Widget) ddEvent.getData());
        this.selectedWidget = widget;
        droppedWidgets.add(this.selectedWidget);
        /*Test*/
        System.out.println("drop: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < droppedWidgets.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(droppedWidgets.get(i).getId());
        }
    }
```

I hope I've made myself clear and thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Can you elaborate what are you saying *It might also be a problem between Ajax and Spring*. How Ajax might be a problem to Spring?

Comment: I don't really know, I only suppose it. I can drag my Widgets, and as you can see in onDrop function, I use a System.out.println but there none of it in Netbeans' log when I drop it in the DropArea. So I assume that the Ajaxlistener didn't do the job...  And just as I said, when I comment the filter, it works. So it has probably smth to do with spring or its configuraation. But if you has an another theory, I'll read it carefully

Comment: Start by searching in a searchengine on basic debugging knowledge for ajax, jsf and web in general. 'doesn't work' is to vagueto be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I post here, it's because I haven't found a solution/way to fix that. 'It doesn't work' is the only thing I can say, there's not exception thrown, or anything. Like I said before, the only thing I'm sure about is that the function onDrop isn't called if filters are here. I am as put out as you about this problem and lack of information...

Comment: Not called can mean no ajax event happens, nothing is transmitted over the network, something is transmitted but an unexpected error occurs that is only visible in the browser network tab. Lots and lots of things you can and should find out. That is basic debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having tried some modifications in my code and implemented a function to change the dashboard language, a CSRF error was thrown (Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

I added this in my .xhtml form: 
`<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>`

And it works. Thanks everyone.